# Exception Invalid Limit Clauses - Android

Tags: android, json, sqlite, exception

I am trying to put json object in sqlite database

```
private void addList(String info){
    try {        
        JSONObject reader=new JSONObject(info);

        String COMMAND = reader.getString("COMMAND");
        String PARAMS = reader.getString("PARAMS");

        int id = vpictures.InsertList(COMMAND,info);

    } catch (Exception e){
        if (DEBUG_FLAG)Log.d("Log1 ", "adding Exception :"+ e.getMessage());
    }
    return;
}
```

The json object `info` looks like this

```
{
    "COMMAND":"ADD_NEW",
    "PARAMS":{
        "deviceID":"1234",
        "custID":"41701",
        "description":"Ddd",        
        "colTranType":"ABS",        
        }
}
```

This is my sqlite table

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER, DEVICEID TEXT, LTIME INTEGER, LATITUDE REAL,"+
        "LONGITUDE REAL, THEPICTURE BLOB, SENT INTEGER, NOTES TEXT, COMMAND TEXT, PARAMS TEXT);";
```

I am trying to insert `COMMAND` and `PARAMS`.
And my sqlite code looks like this

```
public int InsertList(String COMMAND, String info){

        try {

            JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(info);
            String param_str = reader.getString("info");

            if (_Db == null)
                _Db = getWritableDatabase();

            if (_LastId == -1)
            {
                Cursor c = _Db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"max(ID)"}, null, null, null, null, COMMAND, param_str);
                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    _LastId = c.getInt(0);
                    c.close();
                }
                else
                    _LastId = 0;
                c.close();
            }

            try {

                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("ID",++_LastId);

                cv.put("COMMAND",String.valueOf(COMMAND));
                cv.put("PARAMS",PARAMS);          

                _Db.insert(TABLE_NAME, "", cv);
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("Log2","Error:"+e.getMessage());
            }          

        } catch (JSONException e1) {            
            Log.d("Log2","Error:"+e1.getMessage());
        }

         return _LastId;

 }
```

Basically the exception i am getting from the `addList` function

```
adding Exception : Exception invalid LIMIT clauses
```

How to consider inserting json object into sqlite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the parameters of the [query()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method:

```java
Cursor c = _Db.query(
        TABLE_NAME,               // table
        new String[] {"max(ID)"}, // columns
        null,                     // selection
        null,                     // selectionArgs
        null,                     // groupBy
        null,                     // having
        COMMAND,                  // orderBy
        param_str);               // limit
```

The `orderBy` and `limit` parameters do not make sense. To find the largest ID in the entire table, these parameters must be `null`.

Anyway, there is a [helper function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) that makes it reasier to read a single number from the database without having to muck around with a cursor:

```java
long lastID = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(_Db, "SELECT max(ID) FROM "+TABLE_NAME, null);
```

And if you had declared the `ID` column as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, it would be autoincremented, and you would not have to set it manually.